# Unable to mount NTFS Partition after resizing - "Failed to read last sector"

Tags: mount, gparted, ntfs

I had only 15 GB space for Linux, but I wanted to have more, so I just resized one of my NTFS partitions using GParted. But after resizing I am not able to open the partition neither in Ubuntu 10.10 nor in Windows 7.

I get this error message:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 12: Failed to read last sector (395458824): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda5' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Answer (score 5):

This might do it:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdxy
```

change **xy** in the above to reflect the partition in question, e.g.:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

Example output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... FIXED
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully.
```

Comment: @dgbutterworth I'm not sure if this the right way to make edits. Why not create an additional answer? It's okay if you it's essentially the same as this answer but does improve the whys and hows. You can access your edit if you click on [edit(1)](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/338175) below the answer.

Comment: scratch that, it was just formatting....

Answer (score 1):

Boot from windows installation CD and use recovery console to fix that.

Comment: Thanx for reply but I don't know How to use recovery console.
any help